# Function delete all in arrays class

Tags: java, arrays

How can i delete all the element that are equal to a value i entered 
i tried this code

```
public void deletAll(int v)
{
    if (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == v)
            for (k = i; k < count; k++)
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: is that first if supposed to be a for loop?

Answer (score 11):

You can't *delete* elements from an array.

You can set the value to 0 or whatever... and you could even shift the later elements - but you can't then make the array's length shorter than it was.

So to change your existing code slightly to shift the remaining elements *and* set the last element to 0, all you need is:

```
public void deleteAll(int v) {
    if (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] == v) {
            // Shift all elements. Note the end condition of the loop...
            for (k = i; k < a.length - 1; k++) {
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
            }
            // Set the last element to 0
            a[a.length - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

That's removed the use of `count`, because an array already has a length. If `count` is meant to be "the number of meaningful elements in the array" then you would want to change the code to something like:

```
public void deleteAll(int v) {
    if (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (a[i] == v) {
            // Shift all elements. Note the end condition of the loop...
            for (k = i; k < count; k++) {
                a[k] = a[k + 1];
            }
            // Remember that we've got fewer elements now
            count--;
            // Set the last element to 0 (the one we've just copied into
            // the final "useful" position)
            a[count] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

If you find yourself *wanting* to do this, you should use a `List` instead, e.g. `ArrayList`.

Comment: Another option would be copying all remaining values to a new array, but using Collection classes beats that in performance and simplicity.

Comment: i know it just a word but i meant as you said making it null or 0 :)

Comment: @AbeerEls: So why are you shifting everything in your existing code?

Comment: because the doctor told me that :$

Comment: @ Jon Skeet:  no no no ..i mean i want after making it null to shift it to not have an empty boxes in the middle of the array

Comment: @AbeerEls: Well it can't be null, if this is an `int[]`. But if you shift it, you'll want to set the *final* value to 0. But please, just use `List` instead...

Comment: @JonSkeet:i can't use list the lesson about arrays not lists and my teacher told me to use arrays :(

Comment: @AbeerEls: Well did the teacher give you a *precise* description of what was required? (Because the question certainly doesn't contain that precise description...) You should also explain what your existing code does compared with what you wanted it to.

Comment: @JonSkeet: ok..he said exactly i want you to delete all elements in the array that is equal to the value you entered but in the same time do not make a null places inside the array and he gave us an example of shifting only one element ...just that :(

Comment: @AbeerEls: The very fact that he talked about "deleting" elements from the array suggests that you should at least look for some other way of learning. It doesn't sound like your teacher knows Java terribly well :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess that is a for loop there, it should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    if (a[i] == v)
        a[i] = 0; // or whatever you do with a matching value
```

If you're removing items from array, I think you should do it this way:

```
List<T> b = new List<T>();
for(int v : a)
    if (v != a)
        b.Add(v);
```

And then you can convert that list to an array and change the `a[]` to it. Because you don't know what the size of the new array will be, you'll want to use this approach.

Comment: beat me to the add button by a second haha.

Comment: what is foreach? enhanced for loop is what you need

Comment: I just like `foreach` for how simple it is to use, I know it may be slower than a `for` loop, but then again most of the time people jam the `.Count` property right into it, forgetting it also drains resources every time.

Comment: I was referring to the fact that you used the wrong syntax. You should use `for(int i : a)`

Comment: Well, maybe I am. Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't notice it was Java, not C#. Wrong questions tab :p

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not delete item from array and make size of array shorter than it was declared, you can assign that index value to zero. Try this :

```
public void deleteAll(int v){        
    if (a[i] == v) {
        a[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't check each variable of an array.

Comment: i think it need a for loop!

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with arrays and need to shrink them, you'll have to make a new array.

```
public void deleteAll(int v) {
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    if (a[i] != v) a[j++] = a[i];
  a = Arrays.copyOf(a, j);
}
```